# Mongo tries to connect automatically to port 27017(localhost)

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I am using Spring Rest and Mongo in Maven to make a web service that connects to a server. The problem is that I haven't written any code for Mongo and it is trying to connect to localhost throwing me a MongoSocketOpenException. The only code I've written is a two line code that starts spring from main.This is the stacktrace:

```
2015-12-22 12:46:43.193  INFO 5720 --- [           main] fhirepsos.ws.Server                      : Starting Server on HarisPC with PID 5720 (C:\Users\Haris\workspace\FHIRtoepSOSConversion\target\classes started by Haris in C:\Users\Haris\workspace\FHIRtoepSOSConversion)
2015-12-22 12:46:43.197  INFO 5720 --- [           main] fhirepsos.ws.Server                      : No profiles are active
2015-12-22 12:46:43.260  INFO 5720 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@31f924f5: startup date [Tue Dec 22 12:46:43 EET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-22 12:46:44.007  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-12-22 12:46:44.735  INFO 5720 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9001 (http)
2015-12-22 12:46:44.750  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-12-22 12:46:44.751  INFO 5720 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2015-12-22 12:46:44.865  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-12-22 12:46:44.866  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1610 ms
2015-12-22 12:46:45.161  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.166  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.166  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.167  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.167  INFO 5720 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.393  INFO 5720 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@31f924f5: startup date [Tue Dec 22 12:46:43 EET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-22 12:46:45.467  INFO 5720 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-22 12:46:45.468  INFO 5720 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2015-12-22 12:46:45.499  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.499  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.539  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2015-12-22 12:46:45.726  INFO 5720 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2015-12-22 12:46:45.796  INFO 5720 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-12-22 12:46:45.874  INFO 5720 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9001 (http)
2015-12-22 12:46:45.878  INFO 5720 --- [           main] fhirepsos.ws.Server                      : Started Server in 3.033 seconds (JVM running for 3.383)
2015-12-22 12:46:46.764  INFO 5720 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.2.0.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fhirepsos.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>FHIRtoepSOSConversion</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FHIR to epSOS Conversion</name>
  <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency> 
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
       <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.0</version>
   </dependency>     
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
       <artifactId>hapi-fhir-base</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
       <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu2</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>        
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>spring-releases</id>
          <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>  
</project>
```

Finally I have to state that despite the exception the program works fine

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Spring Boot has a feature called "auto configuration". In this case, as soon as the Mongo driver is detected on the classpath, the MongoAutoConfiguration is activated with default values, which point to localhost:27017. If you don't want that behaviour, you can now either configure the properties for MongoDB (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb for valid property keys) or disable the MongoAutoConfiguration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class}) if using EnableAutoConfiguration annotation.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with the async driver of MongoDB. Excluding the above auto configuration classes seems to give no result. Have you any idea of what is going on? I have also open a question on this issue, [Spring Boot Starter-Web tries to connect to Mongo at startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745157/spring-boot-starter-web-tries-to-connect-to-mongo-at-startup)

Comment: This is just preventing error logs in the console to appear, but still the control goes to SilentExitExceptionHandler and throw SilentExitException if start the application in debug mode.

Answer (score 8):

In some cases, if you are using reactive you also need to remove MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: I do not understand. then how do you connect to the DB?

Comment: @RamPrakash, this is only applicable when you don't have a DB connection.

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot throws this exception when Mongo DB is not running. Please make sure that Mongodb is running. It got resolved for me after starting Mongo DB.

Comment: Can you help, how to start MongoDB in spring boot application

Answer (score 2):

for springboot, you should add following config to your application.property

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost(your mongo server)
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017(mongo port)
```