# Spring Boot Starter-Web tries to connect to Mongo at startup

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am experiencing some problems using Spring Boot and MongoDB external driver. I can't use the project Spring Data MongoDB, because I need to use the ufficial async driver given by Mongo. However, I need to use Spring Boot, because the module I am developing is part of a bigger project using this library.

Here is my `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>tx-view</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- omissis -->

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In detail, I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Mongo Async Driver 3.2.2.

Here is my application.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TxViewApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TxViewApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${mongo.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
    }
}
```

It follows the only (empty) test I have at the moment.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void loadContext() throws Exception {}
}
```

I have **no other code** in this project. When I run the test, I have the following error:

```
2016-11-22 15:43:58.597  INFO 4572 --- [null'}-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server db:27017

com.mongodb.MongoException: java.io.IOException: Il computer remoto ha rifiutato la connessione di rete.

at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:125) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Il computer remoto ha rifiutato la connessione di rete.

at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:309) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Iocp.java:46) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:399) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
... 1 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, I have properly inserted the `exclude` clause in the `SpringBootApplication` annotation in order to stop Spring Boot to try handle its own the connection to Mongo, as suggested in [Mongo tries to connect automatically to port 27017(localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414367/mongo-tries-to-connect-automatically-to-port-27017localhost).

I have also noticed that I started to have the error after the addition to the `pom.xml` of the dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web`.

How can I inhibit Spring Boot to try to connect automatically to Mongo at startup? The same problem is present with the synchronous version of MongoDB driver.

**--- EDIT ---**

I have also try to build a wrapper around the `async.MongoClient` object, in this way:

```
public class MongoWrapper {
    private final MongoClient mongo;

    public MongoWrapper() {
        mongo = MongoClients.create();
    }

    public MongoClient getMongo() {
        return mongo;
    }
}
```

The configuration was changed accordingly.

```
@Bean
public MongoWrapper mongo() {
    return new MongoWrapper();
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing had changed. Spring Boot seems to intercept the `MongoClient` object also in this way :(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe `SpringBootTest` does not use `TxViewApplication` as the source of the context because you have another `@SpringBootConfiguration` somewhere else. If you exclude mongo, why do you define a `MongoClient` in the same class then?

Comment: The code that I have posted it's the only one in the project. I merged the configuration in the same class that starts the application to have less code to show. Did you mean that I have no to define any object of type MongoClient in the Spring configuration?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, how do you suggest to integrate the async java driver of MongoDB with Spring Boot?

Comment: If you exclude the auto-config, it does not make sense that we attempt to connect on startup. Can you share a sample?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I shared a demo project on [GitHub](https://github.com/rcardin/spring-boot-mongodb-async). The `pom.xml` was generated using Spring Initializr. Then I add the dependency to mongo async driver. If you try to run `DemoApplicationTests` you will be able to replicate the error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Spring Boot seems to intercept the MongoClient object also in this way". Of course, as your *MongoWrapper* constructor calls *MongoClients.create()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `MongoClient` bean in your own configuration which does not make any sense to me if you've excluded the auto-configuration.

I've commented out the `@Bean` definition in your own config and no attempt to connect to Mongo is performed now. I am not sure I answer to your question and you're probably looking for something else but if you don't want to use mongo, don't define a `MongoClient` in your own config!

Comment: I DO want to use Mongo! But I DO NOT want Spring Boot handling connection to it for me. Then you're saying that I cannot use Spring dependency injection mechanisms to build a `MongoClient` instance without Spring Boot intercepting it?

Comment: Spring boot doesn't do anything. The fact you create this bean definition makes it connect on startup. Spring Boot is not responsible of that at all.

Comment: Mongo driver documentation states that the simple creation of a MongoClient does not Force db connection. How do you explain this?

Comment: Oh so if the mongo documentation states that, it must be Spring Boot's fault? Look at the call stack, there is not a single element related to Spring. Replace your main with the following code and you'll have the exception: ```public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
  System.in.read();
 }```

Comment: You're right, I am sorry. I trusted the Mongo client documentation. Running the example code you gave in the last comment rised the exception too :(

Comment: I will try to ask to MongoDB people what's going on. Thanks a lot for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

This helped us to disable async java driver of MongoDB to use default configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class})
```