# Suddenly can't connect to mongoDB atlas cloud with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Few days ago I could load my Spring application without problems. 
Yesterday I started receiving communicates:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
... 3 common frames omitted
```

and after some time I receive another one

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importVocabularyCollection' defined in file [E:\AGH\Portfolio\Own projects\dictionary\target\classes\com\tchorek\dictionary\database\ImportVocabularyCollection.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tchorek.dictionary.database.ImportVocabularyCollection]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.tchorek.dictionary.DictionaryApplication.main(DictionaryApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tchorek.dictionary.database.ImportVocabularyCollection]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-
5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE] 
at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by:
```

I have already tried `reset --hard` with previous commits, when the app was functioning normally but it did not help. I can still connect to cluster and get elements by public static void main but I have no idea why Spring react like this.

```
@Component
public class ImportVocabularyCollection {

private FindIterable<Document> doc;
private MongoClient mongoClient;
private ArrayList<Vocabulary> vocabulary = new ArrayList<>();

public ImportVocabularyCollection(MongoClient mongoClient){
    this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    this.checkAndGetDatabaseCollection();
}

public ArrayList<Vocabulary> checkAndGetDatabaseCollection(){
    this.doc = getAllObjects();
    this.vocabulary.clear();
    this.convertDocumentToVocabulary();
    return this.getVocabulary();
}

private FindIterable<Document> getAllObjects() {
    return mongoClient.getDatabase("Dictionary").getCollection("Vocabulary").find();
}

private void convertDocumentToVocabulary() {
    for (Document document : doc) vocabulary.add(new Vocabulary(document));
}

public ArrayList<Vocabulary> getVocabulary() {
    return vocabulary;
}
}
```

Comment: Good article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414367/mongo-tries-to-connect-automatically-to-port-27017localhost

Comment: At first when I used that solution I just got a different error. I found out that was my application's fault so yes, that article is the perfect when Spring looks for database on it's own.