# Spring Docker Container stops because it tries to connect to localhost MongoDB even though it already connects correctly to MongoDB Container

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker

Edit: The solution is as described by Valijon. But in addition, the following line was missing before my first insert in the DemoApplication.java:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(new ConnectionString("mongodb://docker_mongo:27017/db")));
```

---

so I wrote a very basic Spring application that is supposed to connect to a MongoDB, store some data, retrieve it and print some stuff for testing purposes.

For that purpose, I use `docker-compose up` to create a container "docker_mongo" and one called "docker_spring".

Now the connection to the Mongo container is actually successfull (see logs), but after that, the Spring container tries to establish another connection to a standard MongoDB on localhost:27017. And that then fails which leads to the container to exit with code 1.
I also edited my `application.properties` (see below).

I guess it has something to do with Spring Mongo autoconfiguration and I already tried to deactivate it as described in this post: [Mongo tries to connect automatically to port 27017(localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414367/mongo-tries-to-connect-automatically-to-port-27017localhost).

However, deactivating the autoconfiguration leads to other errors that I have no idea how to solve right now (I guess I have to refactor the way I connect to the MongoDB in my Spring application and I did not find simple enough tutorials on the internet that tells me how to do that without using the autoconfig features).

I am really a beginner when it comes to coding, so sorry when the question is of poor quality or a duplicate <3 (I googled quite some hours until now though...)

I feel like the solution is really simple, but I just found no article that covers exactly my issue :'(

application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongo
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=db
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://docker_mongo:27017/db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /tmp/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/tmp/app.jar"]
RUN echo "hello world"
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    container_name: docker_mongo
    networks:
      - gateway
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    hostname: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --port 27017
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db

  spring:
    build: .
    container_name: docker_spring
    networks:
      - gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    hostname: spring
    depends_on:
      - mongo

networks:
  gateway:
    driver: "bridge"
```

DemoApplication.java that is being called by the main (I outsourced that into a separate class):

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.model.Expenditure;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

import java.time.LocalDate;

/*
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
*/

@SpringBootApplication

@ComponentScan({"com.example.client","com.example.demo","com.example.model"})
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ExpenditureRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(MongoClients.create(), "db"));
        mongoOps.insert(new Expenditure("Aldi",10.01, LocalDate.parse("2019-10-05")));
        System.out.println(mongoOps.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Aldi")),Expenditure.class));

        mongoOps.dropCollection("expenditure");
        PopulateExpenditureDB.populateExpenditures(mongoOps);


    }

}
```

MongoDbFactory.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public interface MongoDbFactory {
    MongoDatabase getDb() throws DataAccessException;

    MongoDatabase getDb(String dbName) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

ExpenditureRepository.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.model.Expenditure;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

//mongodb Host & Port defined in application.properties

public interface ExpenditureRepository extends MongoRepository<Expenditure, String> {
    /*
    public void create(Expenditure expenditure) {
        if(expenditure.)
    }
    public Expenditure findById(int id) {
        return data.get(id)
    }
     */
    public Expenditure findByName (String name);
    public List<Expenditure> findByExDate (LocalDate exDate);
}
```

Docker logs:

```
~/new_Webapp$ sudo docker-compose up
Creating network "newwebapp_gateway" with driver "bridge"
Building spring
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:11
 ---> 612d4d483eee
Step 2/6 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Running in 3aff2f893162
Removing intermediate container 3aff2f893162
 ---> 2bf19d4c67b1
Step 3/6 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Running in b7c3782bbc1a
Removing intermediate container b7c3782bbc1a
 ---> b029607db12b
Step 4/6 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} /tmp/app.jar
 ---> f3168bc17ae3
Step 5/6 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/tmp/app.jar"]
 ---> Running in f729f7204cdd
Removing intermediate container f729f7204cdd
 ---> aceb4c1a0bda
Step 6/6 : RUN echo "hello world"
 ---> Running in d4ab9bb0f498
hello world
Removing intermediate container d4ab9bb0f498
 ---> 45ae63ef2bd1
Successfully built 45ae63ef2bd1
Successfully tagged newwebapp_spring:latest
WARNING: Image for service spring was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating docker_mongo ... 
Creating docker_mongo ... done
Creating docker_spring ... 
Creating docker_spring ... done
Attaching to docker_mongo, docker_spring
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.462+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mongo
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*", port: 27017 } }
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.464+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7471M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.877+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086726:877548][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 36 through 37
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.904+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086726:904522][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 37 through 37
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:26.950+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086726:950147][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 36/5888 to 37/256
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.008+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086727:8723][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 36 through 37
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.044+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086727:44798][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Recovering log 37 through 37
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.075+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1581086727:75209][1:0x7ff0c5201b00], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0,0)
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.102+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.106+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.109+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.110+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.110+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.110+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.112+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.114+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.114+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.114+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.116+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.116+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.118+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.118+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.118+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Listening on 0.0.0.0
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.118+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:27.118+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
docker_spring | 
docker_spring |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
docker_spring |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
docker_spring | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
docker_spring |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
docker_spring |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
docker_spring |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
docker_spring |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:27.552  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.MainClass               : Starting MainClass v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on spring with PID 1 (/tmp/app.jar started by root in /)
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:27.556  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.MainClass               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:27.950  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:27.992  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:28.000+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.364  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.372  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.372  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.425  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 822 ms
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.616  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[docker_mongo:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:28.643+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.0.3:53260 #1 (1 connection now open)
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:28.649+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 192.168.0.3:53260 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.11.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "5.3.0-28-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.6+10" }
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.659  INFO 1 --- [ker_mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to docker_mongo:27017
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.663  INFO 1 --- [ker_mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=docker_mongo:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2669943}
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.703  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.703  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.717  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.717  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.951  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.076  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.078  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.MainClass               : Started MainClass in 1.787 seconds (JVM running for 2.142)
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.081  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.083  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.083  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.085  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.085  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.086  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
docker_spring | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     ... 3 common frames omitted
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:29.119  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:59.125  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:59.131 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at com.example.demo.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:8) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring | Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:90) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2902) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:587) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1494) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1294) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1226) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1211) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:40) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     ... 13 common frames omitted
docker_spring | Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:145) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:100) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:277) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:201) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1048) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:498) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:482) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:476) ~[mongodb-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$16(MongoTemplate.java:1500) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:585) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
docker_spring |     ... 19 common frames omitted
docker_spring | 
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:59.140  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:59.146+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 192.168.0.3:53260 (0 connections now open)
docker_spring exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple

> `MongoClients.create()` without any parameters to connect to a MongoDB instance running on localhost on port 27017.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver-async/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/#connect-to-a-standalone-mongodb-instance

Spring Boot already connected to MongoDB

```
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.616  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[docker_mongo:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:28.643+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.0.3:53260 #1 (1 connection now open)
docker_mongo | 2020-02-07T14:45:28.649+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 192.168.0.3:53260 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|legacy", version: "3.11.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "5.3.0-28-generic" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.6+10" }
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.659  INFO 1 --- [ker_mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to docker_mongo:27017
docker_spring | 2020-02-07 14:45:28.663  INFO 1 --- [ker_mongo:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=docker_mongo:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2669943}
```

Change to this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.client","com.example.demo","com.example.model"})
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOps;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        mongoOps.insert(new Expenditure("Aldi",10.01, LocalDate.parse("2019-10-05")));
        System.out.println(mongoOps.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Aldi")),Expenditure.class));

        mongoOps.dropCollection("expenditure");
        PopulateExpenditureDB.populateExpenditures(mongoOps);  

    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the issue :)
But one thing I needed to do which is different from your code is to insert the following line before my first insert:

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(new ConnectionString("mongodb://docker_mongo:27017/db")));

Otherwise mongoOps would not be set.

Comment: @Dannnn It's not necessary. `@Autowired private MongoOperations mongoOps` already gets singleton from Spring context. Try it