# Why is MongoDB connection timing out on ecs/ec2 but works fine locally and ecs/fargate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am deploying a Spring Boot application on ecs. We want to move from fargate to ec2, but for some reason the mongodb connection is timing out. It works locally and through fargate, so we're not sure what is causing the issue. I saw another post that was similar to this, but it was a connection refusal ([text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414367/mongo-tries-to-connect-automatically-to-port-27017localhost/34415014#34415014)) rather than a timeout, so that is why I'm asking about this. Here is the error:

Update: I updated the stack trace.

Update 2: I used awsvpc for network mode.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:299) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted

Root Issue:

2024-03-03T22:19:48.746Z  INFO 6 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@66b65db6 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=ac-kgxtec5-shard-00-00.fk3mwfb.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out}}, ServerDescription{address=ac-kgxtec5-shard-00-01.fk3mwfb.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out}}, ServerDescription{address=ac-kgxtec5-shard-00-02.fk3mwfb.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms
```

Comment: My guess is that you have your EC2/ECS inside a VPC that doesn't have/grant access to the MongoDB. If it is an external (to AWS) service, you need a NAT gateway (assuming that your EC2/ECS is/are in the private network of the VPC. If it is an AWS service you use for MongoDB, you probably just need to add a rule to the Security Group and/or a role to the ECS/EC2 to grant access.

Comment: @grekier the security groups are set to allow all traffic and that its coming from a  alb whos security group also allows all traffic. And the security groups and subnets are identical to the fargate deployment, which was successful. If that was the issue, wouldn't it do the same in fargate?

Comment: Are you sure that the Fargate deployment and EC2/ECS are in the same VPC and subnets?

Comment: What network mode did you select when you deployed your ECS task to EC2? When you deploy ECS tasks to Fargate they always use the `awsvpc` network mode. If you are using a different network mode for your EC2 deployment your tasks may not have network access. Please update your question to include more details like this.

Comment: @MarkB, I chose awsvpc when launching the ec2 service.